# Building Turing Machine to list all the integers in order?

Tags: grammar, enumeration, computation-theory, turing-machines

I am learning about Turing machines and I am wondering how to all the int using a turing machine.

Comment: In next some sections you will encounter "[enumerator turing machine](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22558/does-an-enumerator-print-the-first-occurrence-of-a-word-in-finite-time)" in your text book that is what your are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers are also a question of encoding.

You could use the unary encoding:

```
1 = I
2 = II
3 = III
```

and so on.

But you can never list all integers. There are too many. The band is endless and it takes endless time to use it up.

You can accept all integers. So if an integer is on the band then you can accept if it is 0-9 for example and reject if there is another letter.